# How to adjust the size of the container based on the contents without repeating same lines of code?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, css-grid, styled-components

I have few components rendered on based on certain conditions because of which the parent container sizing has to change.

```jsx
export const Container = styled.div`
  display: grid;
  font-family: Nunito Sans;
  padding: 32px 40px 80px 80px;
  background-color: transparent;
  grid-template-columns: 980px;
  grid-template-rows: 40px minmax(64px, max-content);
  ${props =>
    props.extra &&
    css`
      grid-template-rows: 40px min-content minmax(64px, max-content);
  `};
  grid-row-gap: 16px;
`;
```

I am adding the prop `extra` so that the sizing of the container changes based on the addition of the components.

```jsx
renderData = () => {

  const attachments = [a, b, c, d, e];

  if ( attachments.length > 0 ) {
    return ( 
      <Container extra>
        <DetailsHeader  />
        <DetailsAttachments attachments={attachments} />
        <DetailsMisc />
       </Container>
    )
  } 
  return (
    <Container>
      <DetailsHeader  />
      <DetailsMisc />
    </Container>
  )
};
```

So in the above code most of the line of code is repeating.

Basically if there is items in the array of attachments only show the component `DetailsAttachments` else show the normal container with 2 components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to define a boolean variable to have a flag if there are attachments or not and then use it to set the `extra` prop and to render or not the `DetailsAttachments` component like this:

```jsx
renderData = () => {
  const attachments = [a, b, c, d, e];

  // Define a flag to easy check if attachments has elements
  const extra = attachments.length > 0;

  return (
    <Container extra={extra}>
      <DetailsHeader/>
      {extra && <DetailsAttachments attachments={attachments} />}
      <DetailsMisc />
    </Container>
  );
};
```